# this changes value in default and non-default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, this

I have a problem where I need to initialise a member object via a non-default constructor. However the compiler insists that I create a default constructor for the member object, which is called before the non-default constructor.

Consequently, the "this" pointer for the member object has different values in the default and non-default constructor but seems to stablise to the value in the default constructor.

I'm sure this is because I'm not using intialisation properly in C++, but I'm not sure what the correct way is to handle this.

Below is code which demonstrates the issue.

```
#include<iostream>

class my_object {
    public:
        my_object(int a) {
            std::cout << "In non-default constructor for B\n";
            std::cout << "Address of object is " << this << "\n\n";
        }
        my_object() {
            std::cout << "In default constructor for B\n";
            std::cout << "Address of object is " << this << "\n\n";
        }
};

class my_first_object {
    public:
        my_first_object() {
            std::cout << "In constructor for A\n";
            std::cout << "The address of B is " << &B << "\n\n";    
            B = my_object(0);
            std::cout << "We have just called the non-default constructor for B\n";
            std::cout << "The address of B is " << &B << "\n\n";    
        }
        
    my_object B;    
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "\n";
    my_first_object A = my_first_object();
    std::cout << "The address of A.B is " << &A.B << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this programme is

```
            In default constructor for B
            Address of object is 0x7ffee5d83ae8

            In constructor for A
            The address of B is 0x7ffee5d83ae8

            In non-default constructor for B
            Address of object is 0x7ffee5d83a90

            We have just called the non-default constructor for B
            The address of B is 0x7ffee5d83ae8
        
            The address of A.B is 0x7ffee5d83ae8
```

Comment: The code and output seem fine. Are you asking where this `0x7ffee5d83a90` address comes from, and why it's different than the others?

Comment: @cigien Yes that's right. I think that gaurav bharadwaj and molbdnilo both fully answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loooking at `this` in two different objects - the second is created in the assignment

```
B = my_object(0);
```

which creates another `my_object` and assigns its value to `B` (which has already been created).

The only way to initialize members is to use the initializer list:

```
my_first_object() : B(0) 
{
}
```

The reason for the compiler's insistence that you add a default constructor is that if you *don't* initialize a member in the initializer list, it is "default-initialized", and  your code is equivalent to

```
my_first_object() 
    : B() // Initialization 
{
    B = my_first_object(0); // Assignment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see program here : http://cpp.sh/2oisg

You need to change, your `my_first_object` `constructor` like this:

```
        my_first_object(int a = 0):B(a) {
            std::cout << "In constructor for A\n";
            std::cout << "The address of B is " << &B << "\n\n";    
            // B = my_object(0);
            std::cout << "We have just called the non-default constructor for B\n";
            std::cout << "The address of B is " << &B << "\n\n";    
        }
```

This way you are preventing a call to default constructor of `my_object`